# How to split a string in a smart way?

Tags: postgresql

Function string_to_array splits strings without grouping substrings in apostrophes:

```
# select unnest(string_to_array('one, "two,three"', ','));
 unnest
--------
 one
 "two
 three"
(3 rows)
```

I would like to have a smarter function, like this:

```
# select unnest(smarter_string_to_array('one, "two,three"', ','));
 unnest
--------
 one
 two,three
(2 rows)
```

**Purpose.**

I know that `COPY` command does it in a proper way, but I need this feature internally.
I want to *parse* a text representation of rows of existing table. Example:

```
# select * from dataset limit 2;
 id |      name       | state  
----+-----------------+--------
  1 | Smith, Reginald | Canada
  2 | Jones, Susan    | 
(2 rows)

# select dataset::text from dataset limit 2;
           dataset            
------------------------------
 (1,"Smith, Reginald",Canada)
 (2,"Jones, Susan","")
(2 rows)
```

I want to do it dynamically in a plpgsql function for different tables. I cannot assume constant number of columns of a table nor a format of columns values.

Comment: You're trying to parse CSV in SQL?

Comment: @muistooshort - yes, in a certain sense. I have added en explanation.

Comment: Why would you want to parse `dataset::text` in SQL when you have access to lots of data types that won't require all that?

Comment: @muistooshort - I tried to explain this in the last paragraph of the question. I want to apply one algorithm to many different tables.

Comment: I'd recommend deleting this question and asking the question you really want to ask. Parsing the text representation of a row is your *solution*, not your *question*. You seem to really want to work with ROWs in Pl/pgSQL so that you don't have to parse strings at all.

Comment: @muistooshort - Maybe my question was not quite clear, but I have got an answer which seems to be an excellent solution. Thanks for your tips.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a nice method to transpose a whole table into a one-column table:

```
select (json_each_text(row_to_json(t))).value from dataset t;
```

If the column id is unique then

```
select id, array_agg(value) arr from (
    select row_number() over() rn, id, value from (
        select id, (json_each_text(row_to_json(t))).value from dataset t
        ) alias
    order by id, rn
    ) alias
group by id;
```

gives you exactly what you want. Additional query with row_number() is necessary to keep original order of columns.